# Cyclic dependency in module 'CoreFoundation': CoreFoundation -> SpriteKit -> CoreGraphics -> CoreFoundation

Tags: xcode, github, compiler-errors, dependencies

I've got a perfectly running sprite-kit project cloned from github to my mac, and i keep getting multiple compiling errors as the one in the title.

The project works well on all supported devices and simulators in my friends mac, which has the same Xcode Version 5.0.2, ios7+. I have no clue where I'm getting this error from, it comes from native libraries such as corefoundation. Has anyone ever seen this error before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems to be a bug in xcode 5 and github. I've tried doing git checkout to older commits, till I found one that  did work. then I did git checkout back to the latest commit, and it would magically work. the problem may reappear often, but then just repeating the process will do, as it did for me a couple of times.